# Recommendation for Finite Difference Method in Scientific Python

Tags: python, finite-difference, reference-request, hyperbolic-pde

For a project I am working on (in hyperbolic PDEs) I would like to get some rough handle on the behavior by looking at some numerics. I am, however, not a very good programmer.

**Can you recommend some resources for learning how to effectively *code* finite difference schemes in Scientific Python (other languages with small learning curve also welcome)?**

To give you an idea of the audience (me) for this recommendation:

- I am a pure mathematician by training, and am somewhat familiar with the theoretical aspects of finite difference schemes
- What I need help with is how to make the computer compute what I want it to compute, especially in a way that I don't duplicate too much of the effort already put in by others (so as to not re-invent the wheel when a package is already available). (Another thing I would like to avoid is to stupidly code something by hand when there are established data structures fitting the purpose.)
- I have had some coding experience; but I have had none in Python (hence I don't mind if there are good resources for learning a different language [say, Octave for example]).
- Books, documentation would both be useful, as would collections of example code.

Comment: The main problem is that I don't even know where to start looking: so even basic suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: The restriction is only that I am not (yet) familiar with finite volume methods; so I will have to learn the method in conjunction. I would not object to such an answer, of course.

Comment: [PyClaw](http://numerics.kaust.edu.sa/pyclaw/) can handle nonlinear source terms, but writing your own Riemann solver would be complicated, particularly in 2nd or higher dimensions.  If you want to try a simple finite-differencing scheme with structured grids, your next option would be to try something in [petsc4py](http://code.google.com/p/petsc4py/), (Disclosure: I'm affiliated with this project as well), which is more general purpose and not as well-documented.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3451/discussion-between-aron-ahmadia-and-willie-wong)

Comment: Hi Willie (and for readers that haven't looked at the chat), I think you already know this, but since you mentioned hyperbolic PDEs you'd probably be better off with a finite volume method.

Comment: Hi, Willie, finite differences doesn't work quite well for hyperbolic PDEs especially when it is nonlinear, even it couldn't capture the true solution of a simple transport equation where discontinuities are present, I wonder by any chance if you could share with us a minimal example of the equation you want to solve.

Comment: @Shuhao: discontinuities will not be a problem (that I need to worry about), see my discussion with Araon Ahmadia linked above.

Comment: See [New technique for solving time fractional wave equation: Python](http://scik.org/index.php/jmcs/article/view/6048)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a 97-line example of solving a simple multivariate PDE using finite difference methods, contributed by [Prof. David Ketcheson](http://web.kaust.edu.sa/faculty/davidketcheson/Home.html), from the [py4sci repository](https://github.com/ahmadia/py4sci/) I maintain.  For more complicated problems where you need to handle shocks or conservation in a finite-volume discretization, I recommend looking at [pyclaw](http://numerics.kaust.edu.sa/pyclaw/), a software package that I help develop.

```
"""Pattern formation code

    Solves the pair of PDEs:
       u_t = D_1 \nabla^2 u + f(u,v)
       v_t = D_2 \nabla^2 v + g(u,v)
"""

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.sparse import spdiags,linalg,eye
from time import sleep

#Parameter values
Du=0.500; Dv=1;
delta=0.0045; tau1=0.02; tau2=0.2; alpha=0.899; beta=-0.91; gamma=-alpha;
#delta=0.0045; tau1=0.02; tau2=0.2; alpha=1.9; beta=-0.91; gamma=-alpha;
#delta=0.0045; tau1=2.02; tau2=0.; alpha=2.0; beta=-0.91; gamma=-alpha;
#delta=0.0021; tau1=3.5; tau2=0; alpha=0.899; beta=-0.91; gamma=-alpha;
#delta=0.0045; tau1=0.02; tau2=0.2; alpha=1.9; beta=-0.85; gamma=-alpha;
#delta=0.0001; tau1=0.02; tau2=0.2; alpha=0.899; beta=-0.91; gamma=-alpha;
#delta=0.0005; tau1=2.02; tau2=0.; alpha=2.0; beta=-0.91; gamma=-alpha; nx=150;

#Define the reaction functions
def f(u,v):
    return alpha*u*(1-tau1*v**2) + v*(1-tau2*u);

def g(u,v):
    return beta*v*(1+alpha*tau1/beta*u*v) + u*(gamma+tau2*v);


def five_pt_laplacian(m,a,b):
    """Construct a matrix that applies the 5-point laplacian discretization"""
    e=np.ones(m**2)
    e2=([0]+[1]*(m-1))*m
    h=(b-a)/(m+1)
    A=np.diag(-4*e,0)+np.diag(e2[1:],-1)+np.diag(e2[1:],1)+np.diag(e[m:],m)+np.diag(e[m:],-m)
    A/=h**2
    return A

def five_pt_laplacian_sparse(m,a,b):
    """Construct a sparse matrix that applies the 5-point laplacian discretization"""
    e=np.ones(m**2)
    e2=([1]*(m-1)+[0])*m
    e3=([0]+[1]*(m-1))*m
    h=(b-a)/(m+1)
    A=spdiags([-4*e,e2,e3,e,e],[0,-1,1,-m,m],m**2,m**2)
    A/=h**2
    return A

# Set up the grid
a=-1.; b=1.
m=100; h=(b-a)/m; 
x = np.linspace(-1,1,m)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,m)
Y,X = np.meshgrid(y,x)

# Initial data
u=np.random.randn(m,m)/2.;
v=np.random.randn(m,m)/2.;
plt.hold(False)
plt.pcolormesh(x,y,u)
plt.colorbar; plt.axis('image'); 
plt.draw()
u=u.reshape(-1)
v=v.reshape(-1)

A=five_pt_laplacian_sparse(m,-1.,1.);
II=eye(m*m,m*m)

t=0.
dt=h/delta/5.;
plt.ion()

#Now step forward in time
for k in range(120):
    #Simple (1st-order) operator splitting:
    u = linalg.spsolve(II-dt*delta*Du*A,u)
    v = linalg.spsolve(II-dt*delta*Dv*A,v)

    unew=u+dt*f(u,v);
    v   =v+dt*g(u,v);
    u=unew;
    t=t+dt;

    #Plot every 3rd frame
    if k/3==float(k)/3:
        U=u.reshape((m,m))
        plt.pcolormesh(x,y,U)
        plt.colorbar
        plt.axis('image')
        plt.title(str(t))
        plt.draw()

plt.ioff()
```

Answer (score 10):

You could have a look at [Fenics](http://fenicsproject.org), which is a python/C framwork which allows quite general equations to be solved using a special markup language. It mostly uses finite elements though, but worth a look. The [tutorial](http://fenicsproject.org/about/features.html#features) should give you an impression of how easy it can be to solve problems.

Answer (score 3):

This reference might be very useful for you.
This is an open book on internet. I learned (still am learning), python from this book. I found it very good resource indeed.

http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/

For numerical calculation, One should definitely go for 'numpy'.
(just make sure that you have understood the 'array' and 'matrix' and 'list' properly)
(refer numpy documentation for that)